# How to reduce the width of columns in tablesorter

Tags: css, tablesorter

I'm trying to set the width for the columns in JQuery Tablesorter.

I have an example http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5647/

I have 6 columns. I'm trying to adjust the width suitable to my browser window, but for some reason I'm failing in resizing the width of the header and the items in the `<body>` tag.
In the example, I want the first column to be 10%, the second column to be 10% and the third column to be 10%, the fourth to be 50% and remaining two rows to be 10% each adding to 100%. I tried this:

```
.tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+1) {
width: 10%;
 }
.tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+2) {
width: 10%;
}
.tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+3) {
width: 10%;
}
.tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+4) {
width: 50%;
  }
 .tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+5) {
width: 10%;
 }
 .tablesorter td:nth-child(6n+6) {
width: 10%;
  }
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/5649/, if you want to make columns resizable, you'll need to add `'resizable'` to the `widgets` option, but then you won't be able to resize columns.

Comment: By the way, if a table column has more data than would fit in its designated width, the table simply makes it as wide as it has to. In @Mottie's fiddle, that's what happens with the wider columns in narrow windows. Make the viewport wide enough and the table will obey its css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply width to multiple columns at once.

```
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(1),
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(2),
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(3),
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(5),
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(6)
{
  width : 10% !important;
  min-width : 100px !important;
}
.tablesorter  td:nth-child(4)
{
  width : 50% !important;
  min-width : 200px !important;
}
```

`mid-width` here is just to keep the good look and feel. But you could try playing around and figure out the expected behavior.

Also try setting `resizable_widths: [ '10%', '10%', '10%','50%','10%','10%']` in widget options. But i believe purpose of this option is to keep resizable width saved. Refer to documentation for widget it might help better.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cL2f6k18/

Comment: The `!important` flag isn't necessary in this case.